Equivalence of group action/representation: Tensor Product of Groups
Let $H_1 = \mathrm{GL}(m), H_2 = \mathrm{GL}(n)$ and $G = H_1 \otimes H_2$ and consider the vector spaces $V = F^{1 \times mn}$ and $W = \text{Mat}_{m \times n}(F)$. Consider the following two representations $(\pi,V), (\rho,W)$ of $G$ given by
$$\pi(g \otimes h)v:= v \cdot (g \otimes h),$$ as matrix multiplication, and
$$\rho(g \otimes h)w := g \cdot w \cdot h^{-1}.$$
My questions are the following

Are these two representations equivalent?
As group actions, do these two group actions have the same number of orbits?


There is no such thing as the tensor product of groups. You mean the direct product. The representations are not equivalent, but they do have the same number of orbits, namely $\text{min}(m, n) + 1$.
Write $V_1 = F^m$ and $V_2 = F^n$ for the defining representations of $GL_m(F)$ and $GL_n(F)$ respectively. Then the representations you're interested in are
$$V \cong V_1 \otimes V_2$$
and
$$W \cong \text{Hom}(V_2, V_1) \cong V_1 \otimes V_2^{\ast}.$$
So they are not equivalent as representations of $GL_n(F)$, and you can easily check this by computing the character of multiplication by a scalar $c \in F$. In order to make them equivalent the action on $W$ has to be modified to $(g, h) w = gwh^T$.
However, in both cases the orbits are given by tensors resp. linear transformations with the same rank, so the number of orbits in both cases is the number of possible ranks.

Thank you for your answer. Just to clarify, if I realise $V_1 \otimes V_2$ as $F^{1 \times mn}$ how is the representation $(\pi, V_1 \otimes V_2)$ of $GL_m(F) \times GL_n(F)$ (given in the question as right multiplication) related to the representation $(\pi_1, V_1 \otimes V_2)$ of $GL_m(F) \times GL_n(F)$ defined by
$$\pi_1(g,h)(v_1 \otimes v_2) := g v_1 \otimes h v_2, \quad \forall (g,h) \in GL_m(F) \times GL_n(F), (v_1 \otimes v_2) \in V_1 \otimes V_2,$$
related?

@L-JS: ah, I guess I slightly misread your notation. If you were referring to row vectors then $V$ is not a representation at all. You need to either insert inverses (in which case you'll get $V_1^{\ast} \otimes V_2^{\ast}$) or use column vectors, which is what I assumed you were doing (in which case you'll get $V_1 \otimes V_2$, which is the same as $\pi_1$).
